# JavaScript from a file in Tasker

Tags: android, tasker

Can anyone shead any light on why Tasker won't see to run JavaScript from a file?

I have a simple JavaScript that does an alert to screen
Code:
alert("Hello, Tasker World!");

All I ever get back after timeout from Tasker is:

08.07.35/E add wait task

08.08.21/E Error: null

JavaScriptlets such as the following work, but these seem to be built in functions & I want to run JavaScript from a file.

flash("Hello Tasker world!");

Have tried putting the flash command in the JavaScript file. Results in same error mentioned.

Have tried writing the alert() syntax in the JavaScriptlet field. Doesn't do anything.

Comment: Wouldn't it be smarter to ask this question on the Tasker Forums?

Comment: Yep, was error. Thought was in Tasker Forum when posting.  Maybe mod can move it.

Comment: If you check the website and click the forum button, it takes you to Tasker‘s reddit. I highly doubt a moderator from Stackoverflow will move the question to reddit. Just ask your question agqin there and they will most certainly be able to hwlp you faster and better.

Answer (score 0):

https://tasker.joaoapps.com/userguide/en/javascript.html

Alert is not supprted by Tasker